# Listing pod name which consumes highest CPU

Tags: kubernetes

I have to list the name of the pod which consumes highest CPU. I am close with this command.

```
kubectl top pod| sed -n '2p'
```

It prints `pod-01 34 45Mi`

How do I extract just the pod name out of this.

Comment: To rewind a bit, the top command only gives you an instantaneous reading which is very rarely useful. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Perhaps `awk` may suffice. Print the first column in the text. `k top pods | sed -n '2p' | awk "{ print $1 }"`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with `kubectl top pods`, you are not getting the pod with the highest CPU, but you get the list of pods with their CPU usage. With your command you will get the first listed pod's name, not the one's with highest CPU. The command would be:

```
kubectl top pod --sort-by cpu --no-headers=true | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```